# Create count matrix based on two columns and respective range values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe which looks like below,

```
name,value,id
meanerror,0.55,aa
meanamount,120,aa
meanerror,0.45,bb
meanamount,150,bb
meanerror,0.88,cc
meanamount,110,cc
meanerror,0.1,dd
meanamount,50,dd
```

I would like to create a matrix from this dataframe like below.

```
,         meanamount,    total_y
meanerror,0-100,100-200
0.0-0.5,    1,    1,      2   
0.5-1,      0,    2,      2
total_x,    1,    3
```

what I actually need is, in the matrix, each cell should contain count of ids which has value(from value column) in the range on both x and y axis of the matrix. i.e for example the first cell should contain count of ids with meanamount in range 0-100 and meanerror in range 0.0-5.

I have tried pandas pivot table and crosstab but unsure how to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: please provide a text version of your data and better explain the logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) table:

   ```
   pt = df.pivot(index='id', columns='name', values='value')

   # name  meanamount  meanerror
   # id                         
   # aa         120.0       0.55
   # bb         150.0       0.45
   # cc         110.0       0.88
   # dd          50.0       0.10
   ```
2. [Cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) the amounts and errors into bins:

   ```
   pt['meanamount'] = pd.cut(pt['meanamount'], bins=range(0, 300, 100))
   pt['meanerror'] = pd.cut(pt['meanerror'], bins=np.arange(0, 1.5, 0.5))

   # name  meanamount   meanerror
   # id                          
   # aa    (100, 200]  (0.5, 1.0]
   # bb    (100, 200]  (0.0, 0.5]
   # cc    (100, 200]  (0.5, 1.0]
   # dd      (0, 100]  (0.0, 0.5]
   ```
3. Create a [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) of error x amount:

   ```
   pd.crosstab(pt['meanerror'], pt['meanamount'], margins=True)

   # meanamount  (0, 100]  (100, 200]  All
   # meanerror                            
   # (0.0, 0.5]         1           1    2
   # (0.5, 1.0]         0           2    2
   # All                1           3    4
   ```

Comment: you can also add labels to match the format, +1 ;)